# simple-registration doesn't work

Tags: simple-registration

I have an ee4 site - migrated from ee2. The simple-registration addon (v1.6.3) does not work anymore. Also everything is entered, it throws errors:

[image]

Could you please give some support? What might be the problem?

Comment: It would be helpful if you reported the version of EE that you trying to use this add-on with.  1.6.3 is listed as working with EE4 - but comments on the devotee site suggest issues in migrations between EE2 and EE4 have occurred for others, and they note that support from author is non-existent too.  Given that you are getting some kind of registration form suggests that it is working and so maybe for you too the names of the key fields have changed between the versions of the add-on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JCOGS Design

Thanks, you gave me the right idea. It had to do with the honeypot setting in the congig file. When updating the addon during the migration from ee2 to ee4 these settings were overwritten and were therefore no longer assigned correctly. Therefore the registration was not possible.

After resetting the values the addon works as usual again.